# c# перетаскивающиеся окна как в vs

Tags: c#, visual-studio

у visual studio есть окна, которые можно менять местами, выносить как отдельное окно. Как можно сделать что то подобное на c#(например окно "обозреватель решений"). Буду рад если подскажите для winforms, или wpf[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это называется docking, раньше была такая либа - avalondock, ее можно было юзать для wpf. Пример можно глянуть в моем старом [блоге](https://tym32167.blogspot.com/2011/12/avalonedit-avalondock.html) или на [GitHub](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient), что сейчас с этой либой я не в курсе.

Comment: Может быть это Вам поможет.https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1158455/397512